# Setting an <hr>'s background-image, cross-browser issues?

Tags: html, css, background-image, semantic-markup, horizontal-line

Would there be any problems with using an `hr` element to insert an image (using `background-image`)?

I'm reaching for a nice, semantic option for inserting a hero image that is serving as a page separator. I don't want to use `section` because it's really not sectioning content. Since it's technically a header hero for the content to follow, I could just add it to top of the `section` below it … but `hr` just FEELS right.

A coworker mentioned they think `hr` will ONLY render its `border-bottom` in "certain" (uncited) browsers and ignore all other CSS properties, but I've not seen that documented anywhere.

Semantic/technical thoughts? Have you ever used `hr` this way?

**Edit**

Here's how I'm using it:

```
<style>
    .hero_separator {
      display: block;
      border: none;
      height: 428px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
<hr class="hero_separator" style="background-image: url(<?= $background ?>);"/>
```

Comment: yeah a div would be better practice.

Comment: thanks @Moose, could you explain why? Cheers!

Comment: you know that is actually a very good question. My knee jerk was "no a DIV just feels right!", but after thinking about it, a HR is a thematic break, and a DIV is a division or section. Since both support background images, neither is "wrong code". Only other difference is i dont actually think ive ever seen someone use HR in this manner, and tbh, it never crossed my mind to use it in this manner. But actually i cant really give you a solid answer as to why one is better than the other for this circumstance!

Comment: Im actually gonna go look this up now and see, i applaud you for asking me why actually, you learn something new everyday as they say! I never thought i would be learning something new about HTML after all these years xD

Comment: What you should be aware about, is that some browsers has a border set on the `hr` elements, so to make it look the same it needs a reset, e.g. `hr {
       border : 0;
       height : 15px;
       background : url(hr.gif) 50% 0 no-repeat;
       margin : 1em 0;
       }`

Comment: And here is a reset stylesheet sample: http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Comment: haha @Moose, yeah semantics always seem to be quite subjective. Fear of using the wrong tags (FOUWT?) keeps me up at night, hah. I RARELY use hr tags at all unless a designer has worked them into the comp, and even then I often just use top/bottom borders on `section`tags because thematic breaks usually don't seem like a good content choice for a marketing page. Not saying always, but most of the time IME.

Comment: @philtune: ha yes they are quite subjective. Its actually really interesting knowing what other coders knee jerk solutions to things are. Perhaps its got to do with who/where/how we were taught. Hope you got a decent answer to your question anyways! (Y)